# How to configure multiple domains with letsencrypt on nginx

Tags: ssl, nginx, lets-encrypt

I got some issues when trying to configure SSL for 2 domains (following [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04)). Please help me!

My context is:

- I have 2 domains on my server: **example.com** and **test.com**

I would like to configure SSL for above 2 domains. And here is configuration: 
File `/etc/nginx/sites-available/example`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}


server {
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    include snippets/ssl-example.com.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    root /home/user1/example-com;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location ~ ^/index.php/.*$ {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    access_log /var/log/nginx/example-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/example-error.log;

    location ~ /.well-known {
        allow all;
    }   

    # other configurations
}
```

File `/etc/nginx/sites-available/test`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name test.com www.test.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}


server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    include snippets/ssl-example.com.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

#    include snippets/ssl-test.com.conf;    # I tried with other file but it didn't work
#    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    root /home/user1/test-tk;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name test.com www.test.com;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    # server_name test.com;
    location ~ ^/index.php/.*$ {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    access_log /var/log/nginx/test-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/test-error.log;

    location ~ /.well-known {
        allow all;
    }   

    # other configurations  
}
```

There are not any errors after restared nginx.

I can access with `https://example.com/` and everything is ok with first site. But with second site, it does NOT work. I got warning "Your connection is not private" when accessed link `https://test.com/`.

Comment: Clearly you cannot use `example.com`'s certificate on `test.com`. So you need to investigate why `ssl-test.com.conf` does not work. Is the file missing, is it pointing to the wrong files, are the certificate files missing?

Comment: Thanks @richard-smith. I used 2 commands below: `sudo letsencrypt certonly -a webroot --webroot-path=/home/user1/example-com -d example.com -d www.example.com` and 
`sudo letsencrypt certonly -a webroot --webroot-path=/home/user1/test-tk -d test.com -d www.test.com`, but it works ONLY for example.com, NOT for test.com. There are not any errors, please help

Comment: have same issue with nginx and letsencrypt

Answer (score 0):

Instead of line:

```
include snippets/ssl-example.com.conf;
```

use site-specific configuration (or replace content of `ssl-example.com.conf`):

```
   ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
```

and `ssl-params.conf` should contain something like this:

```
   ssl on;
   ssl_session_timeout 5m;
   ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
   ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';
   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
   ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
```

(not necessarily perfect configuration, but it should do the job). Especially `ssl on;` line is important.